# Are ocamlfind package predicates implemented?

Tags: ocaml, ocamlfind

I have a package named sundialsml, in which I want to load a slightly different .cm(x)a file depending on whether a subpackage named no_sens is loaded.  Promisingly enough, the [findlib 1.6.2 reference manual](http://projects.camlcity.org/projects/dl/findlib-1.6.2/doc/ref-html/r721.html) describes a "package predicate" feature:

> [...] there are package predicates for every package that is finally
>   selected.  [They] have the form "pkg_" plus the name of the package
>   (fully qualified).

So I wrote up this META file, where `archive` branches on the package predicate for the subpackage:

```
version = "2.6.2"
description = "OCaml interface to Sundials"
requires = "bigarray"
archive(byte) = "sundials.cma"
archive(byte,pkg_sundialsml.no_sens) = "sundials_no_sens.cma"
archive(native) = "sundials.cmxa"
archive(native,pkg_sundialsml.no_sens) = "sundials_no_sens.cmxa"
package "no_sens" (
  version = "2.6.2"
  description = "Sundials/ML without sensitivity analysis (CVODE, IDA, KINSOL)"
  requires = "sundialsml"
)
```

But findlib loads sundials.cma regardless of whether the subpackage no_sens is loaded, e.g.:

```
# #use "topfind";;
- : unit = ()
Findlib has been successfully loaded. Additional directives:
  #require "package";;      to load a package
  #list;;                   to list the available packages
  #camlp4o;;                to load camlp4 (standard syntax)
  #camlp4r;;                to load camlp4 (revised syntax)
  #predicates "p,q,...";;   to set these predicates
  Topfind.reset();;         to force that packages will be reloaded
  #thread;;                 to enable threads

- : unit = ()
# #require "sundialsml.no_sens";;
/home/jun/.opam/4.01.0/lib/ocaml/unix.cma: loaded
/home/jun/.opam/4.01.0/lib/ocaml/bigarray.cma: loaded
/home/jun/.opam/4.01.0/lib/sundialsml: added to search path
/home/jun/.opam/4.01.0/lib/sundialsml/sundials.cma: loaded
```

Same happens if I try branching on a top-level package, like `ao`.  In fact, far as I can tell, predicates of the form `pkg_foo` are never defined (unless we say `#predicates "pkg_foo";;` of course).

Am I using package predicates incorrectly?  Or are they not really implemented?  If so, is there any other way to select different archives based on the presence/absence of subpackages?

Please note the point here is to **compute** the archive from the set of subpackages the user selected.  So "why don't you use #predicates" is not the solution I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like that the `pkg_` predicates are not implemented for the `#require` directive at all. Of course, I may be wrong, since I inferred this by just greping the code and experimenting. In fact, it is only implemented in the frontend, so it is also not available if someone is using the library interface (so it will not work out of box for `ocamlbuild`).  Also, the `pkg_` predicate is set only for selected packages, not for installed one. Where selected means, that the package is in the set of dependencies.

Here is an example. We define package `ttt` with the following `META`:

```
archive(byte,pkg_ttt.foo) = "foo.cma"
archive(byte,pkg_ttt.bar) = "bar.cma"

package "foo" (
  requires = "ttt"
)

package "bar" (
  requires = "ttt"
)
```

Now we can verify, that it works:

```
$ ocamlfind c -only-show -linkpkg -package "ttt.bar" main.ml 
ocamlc.opt -I opam/lib/ttt opam/lib/ttt/bar.cma main.ml
```

Note: I've used `opam` instead of a real path to my ocaml installation to shorten the output for readability.

```
$ ocamlfind c -only-show -linkpkg -package "ttt.foo" main.ml 
ocamlc.opt -I opam/lib/ttt opam/lib/ttt/foo.cma main.ml
```

So, everything works, when we use the frontend. But if we will try from the toplevel:

```
# #require "ttt.foo";;
opam/lib/ttt: added to search path
```

Then nothing is loaded at all.

We can also try to use `ocamlbuild`:

```
$ ocamlbuild -classic-display -package ttt.foo main.byte
opam/bin/ocamldep.opt -modules main.ml > main.ml.depends
opam/bin/ocamlc.opt -c -I opam/lib/ttt -o main.cmo main.ml
opam/bin/ocamlc.opt -I opam/lib/ttt main.cmo -o main.byte
```

So nothing is linked, it doesn't work. But if you will use `-use-ocamlfind` option, it will work, since this option prescribes `ocamlbuild` to use `ocamlfind` fronted.

```
$ ocamlbuild -use-ocamlfind -classic-display -package ttt.foo main.byte
ocamlfind ocamldep -package ttt.foo -modules main.ml > main.ml.depends
ocamlfind ocamlc -c -package ttt.foo -o main.cmo main.ml
ocamlfind ocamlc -linkpkg -package ttt.foo main.cmo -o main.byte
```

So, to conclude, the idea was nice, and can work theoretically, but it is better not to use it, since the implementation is not complete.

Comment: Oh my goodness.  Never would have guessed that how to get at findlib makes a difference!  Thanks, I'll probably mae a feature request.